# How Can I Create Multiple MockMvc Objects In A Test?

Tags: spring-boot, testing

I have a Spring test annotated like this

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest
public class StepDefinitions {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

In the tests I insert a record using `mockMvc.perform(post("/api/....`

I validate it by calling the equivalent `mockMvc.perform(get("/api/....`.

However, I am using a distributed database and now want to check that the record is stored in another database with a get request to a different back end.

How do I create a second instance of MockMvc that is linked to a different set of backend controllers and services so that I can use them both in the same test?

**EDIT:**

One option is to not use `AutoConfigureMockMvc` but to specify my context configuration instead with multiple `MockMvc` beans defined with `Qualifiers`

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class StepDefinitions {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("firstMockMvc")
  private MockMvc firstMockMvc;
```

TestConfiguration

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("firstMockMvc")
public MockMvc firstMockMvc(@Qualifier("firstController") MyController myController) {
  return MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();
}


@Bean
@Qualifier("secondMockMvc")
public MockMvc secondMockMvc(@Qualifier("secondController") MyController myController) {
  return MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();
}
```

However, this then causes problems with the `WebMvcTest` configuration.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'firstController' method 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.my.app.web.dto.DataDTO>> com.my.app.web.rpc.MyController.getEmployees()
to {GET /api/employees/employees, produces [application/json]}: There is already 'firstController' bean method
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.my.app.web.dto.DataDTO>> com.my.app.web.rpc.MyController.getEmployees() mapped.
```

This seems like I am going to have to manually wire my whole web configuration.

Is there not an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Creating the MockMvc beans with `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` and adding the `@Qualifier` annoations as mentioned in the edit was part of the solution.

The other part was to remove `@WebMvcTest` and `@ComponentScan` so that the Controller beans from the main package didn't get loaded and cause the `Ambiguous mapping` error.

I had to add beans for my Controllers and services but didn't have to do any extra wiring for the underlying Spring beans (apart from MockMvc).